# SendGrid on Azure to Receive and Parse Emails

Tags: azure, sendgrid

How do I go about receiving emails in SendGrid parsing them and sending the output to Azure. Some specific questions I have:

what is the hostname I should specify on the SendGrid Inbound Parse screen?
does it have to do anything about the server domain I receive emails from? Do I specify the Azure hostname here?

Which URL should I specify? is it the Azure URL I want to forward the email contents to?

Any help is appreciated